# Importing custom images into graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics

How can I import a PNG-file into [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) and use it as if it were created within [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py)?

```
import graphics
from graphics import *

window = GraphWin("gameWindow", 800, 600)
myImage = "myimage.png"
myImage.draw(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How are you going to use it?  Can you post a code snippit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Image class. If the call as only two parameters, will assume that the second parameter is the file path of your file:

```
myImage = Image(Point(5,5), 'myimage.png')
```

The following works fine but I don't think Tkinter (what is used by graphics.py) supports png file format. I had to use a gif.

```
import graphics
from graphics import *

window = GraphWin("gameWindow", 800, 600)
myImage = Image(Point(5,5), "myimage.gif")
myImage.draw(window)
window.mainloop()
```