# Why does this code slow down? Graphics.py?

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I have some code that reads a small BMP (128x96) file and puts the RGB values into a list.

I then run a nested loop and read the RGB values in reverse from the list and draw them on the screen.

It starts quite quickly and draws the first 20 lines in a second, but progressively slows down to such an extent I've never seen it finish.  It only a small 128x96 image.

I feel it's the calls to the graphics.py library, buy why, or is it something else?

I'm running this on a raspberry pi, if that's of use. Python 3.4.2

If your interested in trying you can find the supporting files here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yM9Vn1Nugnu79l1UNShamEAGd2VWF3T4

(It's the graphics.py library I'm using and the tiny bmp file, also the actual file in question called SlowDownWhy.py)

```
import math

import sys

from graphics import *

from PIL import Image


# Initialise Vars for Image width n height

iw=0

ih=0



img=Image.open("ani1.bmp","r")  # Open Image

iw, ih = img.size               # Set image width n height

ch = int(1000/ih)               # Cube height set

cw = ch                         # Cube width set



win = GraphWin("My Window", iw*cw, ih*ch)

win.setBackground(color_rgb(128,128,128))



#Transfer Bitmap RGB vales to csv list - 'RGBlist'

pix_val = list(img.getdata())

RGBlist = [x for sets in pix_val for x in sets]



noe = (iw * ih * 3)-3

x = iw

y = ih

for vy in list(range(ih)):

    y = y-1

    x = iw

    for vx in list(range(iw)):

        x = x-1


        r=RGBlist[noe]

        g=RGBlist[noe+1]

        b=RGBlist[noe+2]


        noe=noe-3


        cx=x*cw

        cy=y*ch



        aPoint = Rectangle(Point(cx,cy), Point(cx+cw,cy+ch))

        aPoint.setFill(color_rgb(r,g,b))

        aPoint.draw(win)
```

It should create a window no bigger than 1000 pixels in height and start drawing the picture from the bottom right to the top left, line by line. but slows down progressively.

Comment: This is not valid python code `'` is not the comment-symbol and the `'''` at the end should also throw an exception.

Comment: Struggled with my 1st post sorry the #'s initiall caused the text to go BOLD and huge so I changed them to '    I've since discovered the issue

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the invalid syntax, this is simply because of the way `graphics.py` is programmed: It is not designed to handle this many objects put onto the screen. (It uses tkinter in the back-end, which will slow down with 128*96=12,288 objects). For rendering images, you should either directly integrate them or use another library, as example pygame.

To integrate it into the `graphics.py` program, there is the `Image`-class, which you overwrote with the `PIL.Image`-library (this is the reason why you never do `import *`). Look here: [Importing custom images into graphics.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249859/importing-custom-images-into-graphics-py)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm only used 'graphics.py' as its the 1st thing I found when I searched for a way to import the RGB values of an image into a list.  Do you know a more elegant way to put the RGB values into a list??   [[cheeky grin]]

Comment: Just putting RGB values into a list? Then you don't need `graphics.py` at all, just remove everything and leave the parts with `PIL.Image`. (e.g. `pix_val = list(img.getdata()); RGBlist = [x for sets in pix_val for x in sets]`)

Comment: I'm very new to python, I'm 48 yrs old and did programing when I was a kid on a commodore 64 for I know BASIC like the back of my hand.  This library stuff is confusing :)  Therefore I have no idea what your talking about in your last paragraph about integrating graphics.py  ( it was part of the example I found for importing image RGB's into a list)

Comment: If i remove `from graphics import *` it obviously throws up errors when it tries to create a Graphics Window, but I'll have a look at `pygame` as I still want a fast way to draw blocks on the screen

Comment: Is `pygame` the fastest was to draw either, individual pixels (of different colours) or rectangle filled blocks?

Comment: `pygame` is probably the fastest still within python, simple because it is the one which exposes the most inner workings. It is probably not the best one to start. To packages, you can read this article to figure out a bit more: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: Thank you..  I've been looking at `pygame` looks quite straight forward for what I want.  And thanks for the reading info on libraries.